# Diff a staged file with one in stash

Tags: git, git-diff, git-stash, git-stage

Is there a --staged (aka --cached) option for comparing files from a git stash?

Here I'm comparing the most recent commit against a staged file (I'm using the explicit @{} syntax, but I know that @{0} can be inferred):

```
git diff stash@{0}:spec/blueprints.rb HEAD:spec/blueprints.rb
```

And here I'm comparing the stashed file with what's on disk:

```
git diff stash@{0}:spec/blueprints.rb spec/blueprints.rb
```

How can I compare what's currently staged with what's in the stash? This doesn't work:

```
git diff --staged stash@{0}:spec/blueprints.rb spec/blueprints.rb
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`git diff --cached 'stash@{0}' -- spec/blueprints.rb`

... It is possible that quotes are not needed, but you never know how your shell can surprise you.

Answer (score 0):

> `:<n>:<path>, e.g. :0:README, :README`
>
> A colon, optionally followed by a stage number (0 to 3) and a colon, followed by a path, names a blob object in the index at the given path. A missing stage number (and the colon that follows it) names a stage 0 entry. During a merge, stage 1 is the common ancestor, stage 2 is the target branch’s version (typically the current branch), and stage 3 is the version from the branch which is being merged.

from [git help rev-parse](http://man.github.com/git/git-rev-parse.html)